# Similar uses of $3+4\cos \phi +2\cos 2\phi $ in the prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This question is about a step in the [usual proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) of the prime number theorem. Use is made of the relation

$3+4\cos \phi +\cos 2\phi =2(1+\cos \phi )^{2}\geq 0,$

a good choice because it gives a convenient number of factors in the expression

$$H(\sigma) = [\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)]^3\left(\frac{|\zeta(\sigma+it)|}{\sigma-1}\right)^4|\zeta(\sigma+2it)|(\sigma-1).$$

So I have seen two arguments regarding this step in the proof and they may both be right. **The first** is from Jameson's *The Prime Number Theorem* at p. 107. The idea is to show there are no zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on $\sigma=1.$

He says that showing $H(\sigma)\to 0$ contradicts his previous lemma, that

$$J(\sigma)=\zeta(\sigma)^3|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^4 |\zeta(\sigma+2it)|\geq1. $$ We know that the middle factor of $H$ as $\sigma\to 1+$ is a derivative and is some finite number. We know that  $\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)\to 1$ as $\sigma\to 1. $ Now Jameson says that $\zeta(\sigma +2it)\to \zeta(1+2it),$ also some finite number. So the "extra" factor $(\sigma-1)$ makes $H\to 0$ contradicting the last inequality above.

The **second** explanation I saw was that if $H\to 0$ as $\sigma \to 1+$ then the factors of $\zeta(1+2it)(\sigma-1)$ become arbitrarily large, small (respectively), contradicting what we know about $\zeta(1+2it).$ This seems to remove the need to show $J(\sigma)\geq 1.$

(The argument in the linked Wiki article seems to say that $\zeta(x)$ has a simple pole at $\sigma=1$ and therefore $J$ tends to zero, for a contradiction. I fail to follow this unless it's shorthand for one of the above arguments.)

> Are both arguments above essentially correct? Is there any basis for preferring one over the other, if I have expressed them correctly?

Comment: Your second argument is not clear. Why would $\zeta(1+2it)(\sigma-1)$ large, small (respectively)? which one becomes large? which one small?

Comment: @i707107: As $\sigma \to1+?$

Comment: The second argument is - as the above comment shows - somewhat unclear. But essentially, it's the same argument as the first. Concerning the wikipedia article, since $1$ is a simple pole, $\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)$ remains bounded as $\sigma \to 1^+$ (it converges to $1$, but that's more than we need). $\frac{\zeta(\sigma + it)}{\sigma-1}$ also remains bounded, as does $\zeta(\sigma + 2it)$. Hence the final factor of $\sigma-1$ makes the whole product tend to $0$. Contradicting $H(\sigma) \geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both arguments are variants of one and the same argument, just differently phrased.

We know unconditionally that

- $J(\sigma) \geqslant 1$ for $\sigma > 1$ and arbitrary $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ (by the $3,4,1$-trick),
- $\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1) \to 1$ as $\sigma \to 1$,
- $\zeta(\sigma + 2it) \to \zeta(1 + 2it)$ as $\sigma \to 1$, and
- $\sigma - 1 \to 0$ as $\sigma \to 1$.

Hence it follows that

$$\lim_{\sigma \to 1^+} \underbrace{[\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)]^3 \lvert \zeta(\sigma + 2it)\rvert (\sigma - 1)}_{A(\sigma)} = 0.\tag{$\ast$}$$

We can conclude the argument in various ways. Without assuming that $\zeta(1 + it) = 0$, from $H(\sigma) = J(\sigma) \geqslant 1$ and $(\ast)$ it follows that

$$\biggl(\frac{\lvert \zeta(\sigma + it)\rvert}{\sigma - 1}\biggr)^4 = \frac{H(\sigma)}{A(\sigma)}$$

is unbounded, and hence $\zeta(1 + it) \neq 0$, for if $1+it$ were a zero of $\zeta$, then $\frac{\zeta(\sigma + it}{\sigma - 1}$ would remain bounded (it would actually converge to $\zeta'(1+it)$).

Under the assumption that $\zeta(1 + it) = 0$, by the previous observation, it follows that $H(\sigma) \to 0$, contradicting $H(\sigma) = J(\sigma) \geqslant 1$ for $\sigma > 1$. This is the first argument from your question.

Or, without using $(\ast)$, assuming that $\zeta(1+it) = 0$ implies that

$$B(\sigma) = [\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)]^3\biggl(\frac{\lvert\zeta(\sigma+it)\rvert}{\sigma-1}\biggr)^4$$

remains bounded for $\sigma \to 1$, and then $H(\sigma) = J(\sigma) \geqslant 1$ for $\sigma > 1$ implies that $\zeta(\sigma + 2it)$ is unbounded, which contradicts the third bullet point above. This is the second argument from your question.

The second bullet point above follows from the fact that $\zeta$ has a simple pole (with residue $1$) at $1$, and it is essential to the argument, in whichever variant one uses it.